# Find the id which appeared only once in the table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the data which had no history in the table, in the below given input data ID 37798411 and 74368539 has history and i need filter out with SQL query.
I have used below SQL but not getting correct result set

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data_set
WHERE
    id IN (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM
        data_set
    GROUP BY
        id
    HAVING
        count(id) = 1)

INPUT

ID           Start_date                    End_date
---------------------------------------------------------
37798411    2023-09-21 00:00:00.000 
37798411    2023-04-27 00:00:00.000 2023-09-20 00:00:00.000
37798411    2022-07-21 00:00:00.000 2023-04-26 00:00:00.000
74368539    2023-09-27 00:00:00.000 
74368539    2023-03-30 00:00:00.000 2023-09-26 00:00:00.000
83851566    2023-09-21 00:00:00.000 
83849576    2023-09-21 00:00:00.000 
84042557    2023-09-21 00:00:00.000 


output 

ID           Start_date                    End_date
------------------------------------------------------------
83851566    2023-09-21 00:00:00.000 
83849576    2023-09-21 00:00:00.000 
84042557    2023-09-21 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please don't add spurious tags; edit them to remove any that don't apply (presumably leaving just oracle and sql?). At first glance your output looks OK - if that is your *expected* output and you're getting something different then please include that, and say why it is wrong. [Seems OK is a db<>fiddle though.](https://dbfiddle.uk/geh8SDew)

Comment: BTW, that is a correct resultset based on what I see your SQL statement is. Maybe you need to update your question to make it more clear exactly what you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: Just a note: always use qualified column names (`object_alias.column_name`) especially when you deal with correlated subquery. In the above query it is allowed for `id` column to be resolved as correlation column, not a subquery column, which effectively becomes `where id is not null`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this, which would return a result set that *excludes* records that have more than one entry in the original table:

```sql
select *
from data_set s
where not exists (
                 select 1 
                 from data_set
                 where id = s.id
                 having count(1) > 1
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function `count()` if supported :

```
SELECT ID,  Start_date, End_date
FROM (
  SELECT *, count(*) over (partition by id) as total
  FROM data_set
) AS S 
WHERE total = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ksrTgQIs)